# Only final entry is added to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, listiterator

I am busy with a program for my final-year project. The following method needs to return a list of combinations, and a combination is a list of LoadCases (variableLoad and permanentLoad are subclasses of LoadCase):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<LoadCase>> strUfCombinations()
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LoadCase>> combinationslist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LoadCase>>();
    int i = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < allvariableLoads.size(); x++)
    {
        combinationslist.add(new ArrayList<LoadCase>());
    }

    ListIterator<ArrayList<LoadCase>> cListItr = combinationslist.listIterator();

    while(cListItr.hasNext())
    {           
        cListItr.next();
        ArrayList<LoadCase> combination = new ArrayList<LoadCase>();

        for(int j = 0; j < allvariableLoads.size(); j++)
        {
            allvariableLoads.get(j).setIsLeading(false);
        }
        allvariableLoads.get(i).setIsLeading(true);

        Iterator<VariableLoad> vLoadIterator = allvariableLoads.iterator();
        while(vLoadIterator.hasNext())
        {
            VariableLoad vload = vLoadIterator.next();
            if(vload.getIsLeading()==true)
            {
                vload.finalfactor = vload.partialFactor.strUf;
            }
            if(vload.getIsLeading()== false)
            {
                vload.finalfactor = vload.combinationFactor * vload.partialFactor.strUf;
            }
            combination.add(vload);
        }

        Iterator<PermanentLoad> pLoadIterator = permanentLoads.iterator();
        while(pLoadIterator.hasNext())
        {
            PermanentLoad pload = pLoadIterator.next();
            pload.finalfactor = pload.partialFactor.strUf;
            combination.add(pload);
        }

        Iterator<LoadCase> combItr = combination.iterator();
        while(combItr.hasNext())
        {
            LoadCase test = combItr.next();
            System.out.print(test.finalfactor+test.name+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        cListItr.set(combination);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    return combinationslist;
}
```

I am using a test class to run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    PermanentLoad testload = new PermanentLoad("DL1", "self");
    PermanentLoad testload2 = new PermanentLoad("DL2", "geofac");
    PermanentLoad testload3 = new PermanentLoad("DL3", "fluid");
    PermanentLoad testload4 = new PermanentLoad("DL4", "geounf");

    VariableLoad vload1 = new VariableLoad("VL1", "imposed", "A");
    VariableLoad vload2 = new VariableLoad("VL2", "wind", "normal");
    VariableLoad vload3 = new VariableLoad("VL3", "imposed", "E2");
    VariableLoad vload4 = new VariableLoad("VL4", "thermal", "normal");

    CasesManager manager = new CasesManager();
    manager.addCase("DL1", "self", "null");
    manager.addCase("DL2", "geofac", "null");
    manager.addCase("DL3", "fluid", "null");
    manager.addCase("DL4", "geounf", "null");
    manager.addCase("VL1", "imposed", "A");
    manager.addCase("VL2", "wind", "normal");
    manager.addCase("VL3", "imposed", "E2");
    manager.addCase("VL4", "thermal", "normal");
    manager.addCase("VL5", "cranes", "normal");

    System.out.println("\n");

    CombinationCalculator calc = new CombinationCalculator(manager);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LoadCase>> combinations =  calc.strUfCombinations();

    Iterator<ArrayList<LoadCase>> cListItr = combinations.iterator();
    while(cListItr.hasNext())
    {
        Iterator<LoadCase> combItr = cListItr.next().iterator();
        while(combItr.hasNext())
        {
            LoadCase test = combItr.next();
            System.out.print(test.finalfactor+test.name+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output when I run the test class is:

```
1.6VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  1.6VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  1.6VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  1.3VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  


0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4  
0.48VL1  0.96VL3  0.48VL4  0.0VL2  1.6VL5  1.2DL1  0.0DL2  1.2DL3  1.2DL4
```

The matrix is printed from within strUfCombinations() and the second matrix is printed from test class by iterating through the final combinationslist. The first matrix is the correct output. It seems to me that the strUfCombinations() method is populating combinationslist with the last combination added.

Can anyone help? Maybe I'm just missing something simple.

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: 1. I'm not sure I understand your question. 2. If the output is not as you expect, your best bet is to debug your code step by step to identify the portion that does not work as expected. 3. Once you have identified that portion, fix it or, if you can't, post that (smaller) portion here with a sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: The section of the code that isn't working as I expected is in strUfCombinations() where I iterate through combinationslist: ListIterator<ArrayList<LoadCase>> cListItr = combinationslist.listIterator();
    while(cListItr.hasNext())
    {           
        cListItr.next();
        ........
And the section where I set the current element to combination:cListItr.set(combination);
        i++;
    }  
Sorry about the broad question, I just included all the code so that an overview of the problem could be seen.

Comment: This is not the answer, but why do you fill the combinationslist first and then replace the items there by cListItr.set(combination); instead of the outer while, use a for like for (int i=0; i< allvariableLoads.size(); i++), create the combination and at the end instead of using the set method just do combinationslist.add(combination). Again you need to debug especially after this set, or add method to see the internal objects of you combinationslist object

Comment: I tried that initially, but it gave a ConcurrentModificationException. I'll figure out a more efficient way of initializing the combinationslist once I'm able to populate it properly.

Comment: I looked through this and see no glaring mistakes.  Obviously the combination list is being modified before main() prints it.  I would use a debugger to step through strUfCombinations() and see where it is changed.

Comment: I used the code ... Iterator<LoadCase> combItr = combination.iterator();
        while(combItr.hasNext())
        {
            LoadCase test = combItr.next();
            System.out.print(test.finalfactor+test.name+"  ");
        } ... at the end of strUfCombinations() to do exactly that. This prints out the first (correct) matrix. Each combination is correct before being added to combinationslist. The problem must be where it is added to the list or where I print out the second matrix from the main().

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `LoadCases` that I used were being recycled, i.e. every element in the arraylist was pointing to a single `LoadCase` which is why all element had the value of the final array.

I solved the problem by writing a `static clone()` method in class *LoadCase* that creates a copy of *LoadCase*. A clone is then created and put into combinations instead of the original LoadCase from `allvariableloads` and `permanentloads`.